# Decomposition of procyclic groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, profinite-groups

I've posted this on ME and even after editing several times, didn't get answers, so I'm moving it here. Please tell me if this is inappropriate for MO community. 
I need help in the following exercise:

**Exercise**

Let $G$ be a procyclic group (a profinite group with a dense cyclic subgroup).

Use that $G$ is a homomorphic image of $\hat{\mathbb{Z}}$ to show there exists a set $S$ of prime numbers such that
\begin{equation}
G\cong \prod_{p\in S}G_{p}
\end{equation}
where either $G_{p}\cong\mathbb{Z}_{p}$ or $G_{p}\cong\mathbb{Z}/p^{i_{p}}\mathbb{Z}$ for some $i_{p}\in\mathbb{N}$.

**My attempt**

Firstly, I note that I'm allowed to use the decomposition of $\hat{\mathbb{Z}}\cong\prod_{p}\mathbb{Z}_{p}$, where $p$ runs by all primes.

Saying that $G$ is a homomorphic image of $\hat{\mathbb{Z}}$ means that it is isomorphic to a quotient of $\hat{\mathbb{Z}}$.

Well, if we assume that closed subgroups of $\prod_{p}\mathbb{Z}_{p}$ are very nicely behaved (for instance, if they were products of closed subgroups of the $\mathbb{Z}_{p}'s$) then we could say something like
\begin{equation}
G\cong \Big(\prod_{p}\mathbb{Z}_{p}\Big)/(\prod_{p}H_{p}\Big)\cong \prod_{p}\mathbb{Z}_{p}/H_{p},
\end{equation}
where $H_{p}$ is closed in $\mathbb{Z}_{p}$. Since such $H_{p}$ must be either $\{0\}$ or $p^{i}\mathbb{Z}_{p}$ for some $i\geq 0$, we find that $G_{p}=\mathbb{Z}_{p}/H_{p}$ can be $\mathbb{Z}_{p}$, or $\mathbb{Z}/p^{i}\mathbb{Z}(i>0)$ or $\{0\}$, which gives us what we want, since the $\{0\}$'s that appear in this new product simply kills the prime associated with it in the construction of our set $S$.

**So, how to proceed for general closed subgroups? Is it true that they are all of this form? Any hints on how I can start to sketch a proof for such claim?**

Thank you guys so much for any help, I'm stuck in this for some time now.

Answer (score 2):

Try this: Just as $\hat{\Bbb Z}$ is the product of its “$p$-parts”, by which I mean the groups $\projlim_n\hat{\Bbb Z}/p^n\hat{\Bbb Z}\cong\Bbb Z_p$, so your group $G$ should be the product its $p$-parts $G_p=\projlim_mG/p^nG$. Each $G_p$ will be either a $\Bbb Z_p$, a finite cyclic $p$-group, or trivial.